# Java - Mix up letters

Tags: java, string, split, shuffle

Can someone give me an example of how to split Strings before you scramble the letters

I can scramble the words but it changes the length of the words too

Example:

> input : Hello my name is Jon
>
> output: e imanoJs  my nlolHe

But it should be like this

> input : Hello my name is Jon
>
> output: Hlelo my nmae is Jon

so the first and last letter should stay in place

here is my code so far

```
public class MixUp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String cards="Hello my Name is Jon, nice to meet you";
        System.out.println("Input String = " + cards);
        cards = shuffle(cards);
        System.out.println("Shuffled String = " + cards);
     }

    static String shuffle(String cards){
        if (cards.length()<=1)
            return cards;

        int split=cards.length()/2;

        String temp1=shuffle(cards.substring(0,split));
        String temp2=shuffle(cards.substring(split));

        if (Math.random() > 0.5) 
            return temp1 + temp2;
        else
            return temp2 + temp1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes

- Use Collections.shuffle() in combination with List.subList() so that the first and last letters are not moved.
- Convert to and from primitive array so that Collections.shuffle() can be used

Code

```
private static String shuffle(String sentence) {
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : words) {
        List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (char letter : word.toCharArray()) {
            letters.add(letter);
        }
        if (letters.size() > 2) {
            Collections.shuffle(letters.subList(1, letters.size() - 1));
        }
        for (char letter : letters) {
            builder.append(letter);
        }
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Maybe using Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray()) is nice than using for-loop. What do you think?

Comment: Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray()) produces a list with one element which is the array. Arrays.asList() only works for wrapper types like Character, not char.

Answer (score 1):

`inputString.split(" ")` will split on spaces and return an array of Strings. Create a new array, iterate through the first split array and shuffle each string and add the shuffled string to the new array.

```
String cards="Hello my Name is Jon, nice to meet you";
System.out.println("Input String = " + cards);
String[] splt = cards.split(" ");
String[] shuffled = new String[splt.length];
for (int iter = 0; iter < splt.length; iter ++){
    shuffled[iter] = shuffle(splt[iter]);
}
// Now join the array
```

**EDIT** Better yet use a StringBuilder

```
String cards="Hello my Name is Jon, nice to meet you";
System.out.println("Input String = " + cards);
String[] splt = cards.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int iter = 0; iter < shuffled.length; iter ++){
    sb.append(shuffle(splt[iter]) + " ");
}
String shuffled = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split the sentence into words and then scramble the words:

```
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

for(String word : words)
   word = shuffle(word);
```

Then concat the word together to a sentence.

Comment: Modifying word does nothing, you'd have to concat to a String that is declared outside of the for loop.